# BusinessObjects Settings for Multiple Environments

Tags: business-objects

I have 3 folders on a server:

- PROJECT_1_TEST
- PROJECT_1_INT
- PROJECT_1_PROD

Each folder contains a universe.
The only difference among universes is that they use different databases - test, integration, production db respectively.

The question is - when I change something in TEST folder, would it be possible just to copy the universe from TEST -> INT or PROD so that the universe in these two folders automatically gets the new changes?
I want to avoid multiple identical changes for every of these universes.
Is it possible to use for example a parameter that uses TEST DB when a universe is in TEST folder, INT DB when a universe is in INT DB, and PROD DB when a universe is in PROD folder???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using IDT, you can quite easily publish the same BL as 3 different universes. The only thing you'll need to remember is to change the connection as you cannot make the connection dependant on the folder the universe resides in.

What you could do is use one single universe, and depending on the user, change the underlying connection.

For example, say you have 3 user accounts:

- user A (test)
- user B (int)
- user C (prod)

Using Data Security Profiles (or universe restrictions in UDT), you can define that the test connection should be used when user A uses a document on your universe, or the int connection when user B does, etc.

Of course, you wouldn't do this with individual users but rather with user groups. Make sure though that a user is a member of only one of these groups.

The advantage is that you end up with only one universe to maintain and publish. However, I don't know you use case, so this may or may not fit.

Look in the [Information Design Tool User Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp3_info_design_tool_en.pdf) section 17.7 for more information on this.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: [Create a data security profile for connection and query options](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-22091). It shows you how to create a data security profile and modify the connection. You'll need three separate such profiles, each pointing to a different connection. Then you have to assign each of those profiles to a corresponding user group.

Comment: Sorry - I deleted the comments (you are too fast).
I think creation of different profiles would not help, since we have only ONE "machine" and that is data warehouse. Furthermore, we have defined one connection "DWH_Conn". This connection has access to all our three environments - TEST, INT and PROD. Therefore, in order to use different environment in our universe(es) it seems to me we have to have some parameter in DATA LAYER. In that case, when we want to give the enhanced version of a universe to our users to test it we copy the universe in INT FOLDER. The parameter should use INT Database

Comment: Would that be possible to implement with IDT?

Comment: You could use the _table replacement_ feature, also part of data security profiles. But again, you can't make this dependant on the folder the universe reside in. This would again be done using one single universe and different user groups. Also, it does imply that the database schema throughout the different databases (test, int and prod) is identical to prevent errors when the end-user tries to create a document on your universe. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-22101) for more info.

Comment: That sounds good. I the bottom line we do not and actually do not need to have only one universe - we would have multiple versions of universes in TEST folder, only one versio in INT, and one version in PROD. The only question that bugs me is, when I want new version in INT folder ie I want to update INT universe, I would take the working version from TEST folder and with that version overwrite the  INT version. Would table replacement help that INT Universe still uses tables in INT database?

Comment: "table replacement feature" was the right solution. Thanks Kristof!